# findById doesn't see the object from the mock

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I am writing a test for the UserServiceImpl service.

```
    public User getUserById(long id) {
        Optional<User> optional = userRepository.findById(id);
        User user = null;
        if (optional.isPresent()) {
            user = optional.get();
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("User not found for id: " + id);
        }
        return user;
    }
```

UserServiceImplTest

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class UserServiceImplTest {

    @Mock
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    @InjectMocks
    private UserServiceImpl userService;

    @Test
    public void shouldReturnUserById() {
        List<User> users = getUsers();
        Long id = 1L;

        Mockito.when(userRepository.findAll()).thenReturn(users);

        System.out.println(users.get(0).getId());

        User result = userService.getUserById(id);

        Assertions.assertNotNull(result);
        Assertions.assertEquals(users.get(0), result);
    }

    private List<User> getUsers() {
        User firstUser = new User();
        User secondUser = new User();

        firstUser.setId(1L);
        firstUser.setName("Rob");
        firstUser.setLastName("King");
        firstUser.setDepartment("Supply");
        firstUser.setPosition("Team lead");

        secondUser.setId(2L);
        secondUser.setName("Mike");
        secondUser.setLastName("Wilson");
        secondUser.setDepartment("Sale");
        secondUser.setPosition("Specialist");

        return List.of(firstUser, secondUser);
    }
}
```

When running a test in the userService.getUserById(id) method - java.lang.RuntimeException: User not found for id: 1
Although there is an object with the same ID in the repository.
Tell me please what did I miss?

Comment: Hi, you are Mocking the findAll and not the findById method. You are using the findbyId in you service.

Comment: your called method `userService.getUserById(id);` calls another method on the repository `userRepository.findById(id);` Since you never mocked the `userRepository.findById(id);` it returns null, hence your exception

Comment: By the way, your getUserById method can be shortened to a single line: `return userRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("User not found for id: " + id));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The main issue here is that you're mocking `userRepository.findAll()` instead of `userRepository.findById(id)`.**

In your `UserServiceImpl` implementation, you're using `findById(id)` to fetch the user, but in the test, you've set up a mock for `findAll()`. These are two different methods, and Mockito doesn't know how to respond when `findById(id)` is called because it hasn't been instructed on what to do in that scenario.

To fix this, you'll want to mock the behavior of `findById(id)`. Here's how you can do it:

`Mockito.when(userRepository.findById(eq(1L))).thenReturn(Optional.of(getUsers().get(0)));`

*Notice the `eq` method which provides you the ability to match specific arguments passed to your mock.*

---

Please be aware that this test, given the simplicity of your service layer, may not be testing meaningful behavior as it mocks the repository and does not cover real database interactions, potentially missing integration issues.

Answer (score 0):

To fix it you should mock `findById(id)` by this syntax:

```
Mockito.when(userRepository.findById(any())).thenReturn(Optional.of(getUsers().get(0)));
```